# Why Expo GoogleSignIn isn't workin locally with ExpoGo

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

In my expo app, I configured google signIn using the package

Everything's working well on production and development builds, but when I'm trying to run my app locally using ExpoGo, I get this error:

[image]

```
Error: RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully.
If you are using Expo, make sure you are using Custom dev client, not Expo go., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
```

How can I solve it so it'd work locally?